# MSMQ storage in database

Tags: msmq

MSMQ stores messages on file system. Is there no way to configure MSMQ to store messages in database? I looked for options but couldn't find any?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way. By the way, why would you like to do that?

Comment: It would have been easy if the storage is in database. In case of a crash disaster recovery site will be activated and for that we are keeping database in sync. If we use MSMQ then we need to keep file system also in sync.

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ isn't a database; it's a transport protocol.
It's purpose is to deliver data from A to B so that you can then process it.
If you're thinking of how to long-term store messages then you are looking at the wrong product.

Cheers
John Breakwell