# Store MSMQ queue in database

Tags: .net, database, msmq

I'm new to MSMQ for .NET and have a question.

For my system I want to use MSMQ for queuing some system requests, but a customer wants to keep all information in database. I wonder is there any way to store MSMQ messages in database?

Currently I see the only way to create some record in database and put record id to queue.

Comment: It's been already asked and answered here on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259298/msmq-storage-in-database. Best answer from Mr. Smith : Read the MSMQ FAQ : http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/techinfo/overview/msmqfaq.mspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would need to read the records from your queue and store in a database. Typically you might do this using a Windows service.

Typically, you only need to use MSMQ if there might be intermittant networking connectivity between two locations or you think the number of requests exceeds what the database can handle in one go. Otherwise, just store straight in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep in all "close" to the database then have a look at the [SQL Server Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).  This is messaging done within SQL Server.